# Coverting map into a json schema

Tags: jsonschema

I want to create the json schema of the following:

My java pojo looks like:

```
public class Filter {

    Map<String, Object> 
    Map<String, Integer> sort;
    int offset = -1;
    int limit = -1;
    List<String> responseFields;
}
```

My sample json looks like:

```
{
  "terms": {
    "foo":"bar",
    "foo1":1
  },
  "sort": {
    "foo": 1
  },
  "offset": 1,
  "limit": 25,
  "responseFields": ["foo", "foo1"]
}
```

I'm stuck at creating the json-schema for the terms and order fields. Can anyone please let me know how i could mode this?

Answer (score 1):

`Map<String, ???>` can be described with `{ "type": "object", "additionalProperties": ??? }`.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "terms": { "type": "object" },
    "sort": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": { "type": "integer" }
    },
    "offset": { "type": "integer" },
    "limit": { "type": "integer" },
    "responseFields": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "string" }
    }
  }
}
```